# how to use wcf and svc in php?

Tags: c#, php, web-services, wcf, soap

I want to connect to a webservice 
Url:

```
https://bill.samanepay.com/CheckBill/BillStateService.svc?wsdl
```

in c# it's working and I recieve data

```
ServiceReference1.BillStateServiceClient bdclinet = new ServiceReference1.BillStateServiceClient();
s=  bdclinet.VerifyBillPaymentWithAddData("4546330305913", "54360101", "10400061", "9768914");
```

but in in `php` response is `null`

```
$client = new  oapClient("https://bill.samanepay.com/CheckBill/BillStateService.svc?wsdl");
$res=  $client->VerifyTransaction("0911229170","1411727361","6010","10780538");
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you turned on error exposure on the php side? By default php supresses most exceptions and error messages, wich is a acceptable strategy at runtime.

But during Development you have to explicitly override that behavior or you never get any debugging data.

Unless you manage to extract an actuall error message from SoapClient or VerifyTransaction, we are both just trying to navigate a very Dark space.